# Show that for every $A \in \delta$ and every $\ x \in \Omega$, it is either $K_x \cap A = \emptyset$ or $K_x \subset A.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ and $\delta \subset P(\Omega)$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. Furthermore, define
>
> $K_x := \bigcap_{A \in \delta  \ : \  x \ \in A}$  $A, \ x \in \Omega$.
>
> Show that for every $A \in \delta$ and every $\ x \in \Omega$, it is either
>
> $K_x \cap A = \emptyset$ or $K_x \subset A.$

**Note:** It actually doesn't matter that $\delta$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. It's just a part of a greater task.

I proved this the following way:

$K_x \subsetneq A \Rightarrow \exists \ x \in K_x \ : \ x \notin A \Rightarrow \forall \ y \in A \ : \ y \notin K_x \Rightarrow K_x \cap A = \emptyset$.

On the other hand, we have

$K_x \cap A = \emptyset \Rightarrow \lnot \ \exists \ x \in \Omega \ : \ x \in K_x$ and $x \in A \Rightarrow K_x \subsetneq A.$

Now I have proven that the negation of both premises leads, as wished, to the respective statements. But since the task is formulated as "either .. or", I wondered whether this already fulfills the task or not. I think I still have to show that at least one of both statements actually are true without using one of the respective premises, haven't I? I have shown that only one of those statements can be true maximally, but I haven't shown that at least (!) one of those statements has to be true, right?

Comment: Well first, it does matter that $\delta$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, because if not, it is possible that $K_x \cap A\neq \emptyset$ and $K_x \not\subset A$. Then, can't you just prove it by dichotomy? Either $x\in A$ or $x\not\in A$...

Comment: You mean, when $x \in A$, we would get $ K_x \subset A$ and when $x \notin A$, we would get $K_x \cap A$?

Comment: Yes. The second statement uses the fact that $\delta$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. \edit : that is if I understand the definition of $K_x$ correctly. I think there is an extra '$=$' there.

Comment: Damn, sorry, corrected it. $K_x$ is just the intersection of every $A \in \delta$ that contains $x$ as an element.

Comment: ... which actually means that $x \in A$ wouldn't be the right approach, would it? $x \in A$ follows from the definition of $K_x$. Isn't it more like $x \in K_x$ or $x \notin K_x$?

Comment: $x$, by definition, is always an element of $K_x$ as long as $K_x\neq \emptyset$. The reasoning I see goes as follows: let $A\in\delta$ and $x\in\Omega$. If $x\in A$, then... if not, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\in\delta$ and $x\in\Omega$.

If $x\in A$ then the definition of $K_x$ implies that $K_x\subseteq A$.

If $x\notin A$ then $x\in A^c$.

This with $A^c\in\delta$ because a $\sigma$-algebra *is closed under complements*.

Then again by the definition of $K_x$ we have $K_x\subseteq A^c$ or equivalently $K_x\cap A=\varnothing$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!